# Can anyone help to save a photo after 5 secs using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I tried to capture using `time.sleep(5)` but I guess that is pausing the camera.. I want the camera to run normal and after 5 secs (after pressing a spacebar) I would like to click a picture and save it..

```
# SPACE pressed
elif k%256 == 32:
        img_name = "opencvframe{}.png".format(img_counter)
        cv2.waitKey(2000)
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, img)
        print("{} written!".format(img_name))
        img_counter += 1
```

Comment: Change this cv2.waitKey(2000) to cv2.waitKey(5000)

Comment: that will still pause the camera..I want the camera to still run.. just changing to 5000 means waiting for 5 secs and this pauses the camera for 5 secs..I want to click the picture after 5 secs..